# Matlab GUI: How to store the order and results of a push buttons

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, push, store

I have a simple GUI with 2 pushbuttons, one says yes the other says no.

How can I record how many times each has been pressed and more importantly the order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the number of "Yes" and "No" you might define in your GUI:

- a counter for the "Yes"
- a counter for the "No"

To keep track of the sequence of the "Yes" and "No" you might defined

- a "global" counter for either the "Yes" and "No"
- an array in which to store sequentialy the "Yes" as, for example, "1" and the "No" as "-1" according to the pushbutton that has been pressed
- a string in which to store sequentialy "Yes" "No" according to the pushbutton that has been pressed

All the above defined variable can be initialized in the GUI `OpeningFcn` and then stored in the structure of the `GUI data` (by using the `guidata` finction.

The variable are then:

- set in the "Yes" and "No" `pushbutton callback`
- stored in the structure of the `GUI data`(again with the `guidata` function

In the "Yes" and "No" `pushbutton callback` you can also print either the number of times the "Yes" and "No" pushbutton have been pressed and their sequence in two `text box`.

You can also use the array in which you've stored the "Yes" / "No" as `1` and `-1` to, for example, plot a graph.

In the following, the coded of the GUI `yes_no_counter` used to test the solution; in the GUI:

- "Yes" `pushbutton tag`= `yes_btn
- "No" `pushbutton tag`= `no_btn`
- first `text box tag`= "text1"
- second `text box tag`= "text2"

**yes_no_counter.m**

```
function varargout = yes_no_counter(varargin)
% YES_NO_COUNTER MATLAB code for yes_no_counter.fig
%      YES_NO_COUNTER, by itself, creates a new YES_NO_COUNTER or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = YES_NO_COUNTER returns the handle to a new YES_NO_COUNTER or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      YES_NO_COUNTER('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in YES_NO_COUNTER.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      YES_NO_COUNTER('Property','Value',...) creates a new YES_NO_COUNTER or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before yes_no_counter_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to yes_no_counter_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help yes_no_counter

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 09-Jan-2016 17:22:23

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @yes_no_counter_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @yes_no_counter_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before yes_no_counter is made visible.
function yes_no_counter_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to yes_no_counter (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for yes_no_counter
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes yes_no_counter wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);

% Get the GUI data
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf);
% Initialize the "Yes / No " counter
my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt=0;
% Initialize the "Yes" counter
my_gui_data.yes_cnt=0;
% Initialize the "No" counter
my_gui_data.no_cnt=0;
% Initialize the "Yes / No " array
my_gui_data.yes_no=[];
% Initialize the "Yes / No " string
my_gui_data.yes_no_str='';
% Store the updated GUI data
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = yes_no_counter_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in yes_btn.
function yes_btn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to yes_btn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get the GUI data
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf);
% Increment the £Yes / No" counter
my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt=my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt+1
% Increment the "Yes" counter
my_gui_data.yes_cnt=my_gui_data.yes_cnt+1
% Store the "Yes" as "1" in the "Yes / No" array
my_gui_data.yes_no(my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt)=1
% Print the number of "Yes" and "No" in the first textbox
set(handles.text1,'string',['Yes= ' num2str(my_gui_data.yes_cnt) '; No= ' num2str(my_gui_data.no_cnt)])
% Build the cumulative "Yes / No" string
my_gui_data.yes_no_str=strcat(my_gui_data.yes_no_str,' Yes');
% Print the cumulative "Yes / No" string n the second textbox
set(handles.text2,'string',my_gui_data.yes_no_str)
% Store the updated GUI data
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);

% --- Executes on button press in no_btn.
function no_btn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to no_btn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get the GUI data
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf);
% Increment the "Yes / No" counter
my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt=my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt+1
% Increment the "No" counter
my_gui_data.no_cnt=my_gui_data.no_cnt+1
% Store the "Yes" as "-1" in the "Yes / No" array
my_gui_data.yes_no(my_gui_data.yes_no_cnt)=-1
% Print the number of "Yes" and "No" in the first textbox
set(handles.text1,'string',['Yes= ' num2str(my_gui_data.yes_cnt) '; No= ' num2str(my_gui_data.no_cnt)])
% Build the cumulative "Yes / No" string
my_gui_data.yes_no_str=strcat(my_gui_data.yes_no_str,' No');
% Print the cumulative "Yes / No" string n the second textbox
set(handles.text2,'string',my_gui_data.yes_no_str)
% Store the updated GUI data
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);
```

**The GUI**

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. I didn't want to display the counter which is why I found it so hard. I was just missing guidata(hObject , handles); after I edited the structure.